# fixed table left column slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created fixed left 2column i need remaining columns with slider ie: when i click left arrow move left side, when i click right arrow move right side.
please find attached image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fixTable").tableHeadFixer({"head" : false, "left" : 2}); 
   });
```

```css
#parent {
    height: 300px;
   }
   
   #fixTable {
    width: 1800px !important;
   }
.arrow_postions{position: absolute;right:0; top:45%;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer/assets/bootstrap-3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer/assets/jquery-2.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer/tableHeadFixer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table id="fixTable" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="text-center font16">J6W47EP#AC4</td>
     <td class="text-center font16 color0070c0">N6E89AV#002</td>
     <td class="text-center font16 color0070c0">N6E89AV#001</td>
     <td class="text-center font16 color0070c0">T4N02LT#AC4</td>
     <td class="text-center font16 color0070c0">N6E89AV#002</td>
     <td class="text-center font16 color0070c0">N6E89AV#002</td>
     <td class="text-center font16 color0070c0">T4N02LT#AC4</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>PROCESSOR</td>
     <td>B5E74AV-AMD A10 -5800B 3.8G 4M 100W CP</td>
     <td>B5E77AV - AMD A4-5300B TBD 1M 65W CPU</td>
     <td>D9E96AV - CPU A A4-5150M Dual Core</td>
     <td>E5T35AV-CPU I Core i7-4600M Dual Core</td>
     <td>B5E74AV-AMD A10 -5800B 3.8G 4M 100W CP</td>
     <td>B5E77AV - AMD A4-5300B TBD 1M 65W CPU</td>
     <td>B5E74AV-AMD A10 -5800B 3.8G 4M 100W CP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>MEMORY</td>
     <td>D0A51AV-8GB DDR3-1600 SODIMM (1X8GB) B</td>
     <td>D0A53AV-8GB DDR3-1600 SODIMM (2x4GB) B</td>
     <td>D3B06AV-RAM 4GB 1600 DDR3L 1DM</td>
     <td>D3B06AV-RAM 4GB 1600 DDR3L 1DM</td>
     <td>D0A51AV-8GB DDR3-1600 SODIMM (1X8GB) B</td>
     <td>D0A53AV-8GB DDR3-1600 SODIMM (2x4GB) B</td>
     <td>D0A51AV-8GB DDR3-1600 SODIMM (1X8GB) B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>STORAGE</td>
     <td>B6P51AV-500GB7200RPMSATA2.52ndSEDw/caH</td>
     <td>B6P51AV-500GB7200RPMSATA2.52ndSEDw/caH</td>
     <td>B6P51AV-500GB7200RPMSATA2.52ndSEDw/caH</td>
     <td>B6P51AV-500GB7200RPMSATA2.52ndSEDw/caH</td>
     <td>B6P51AV-500GB7200RPMSATA2.52ndSEDw/caH</td>
     <td>B6P51AV-500GB7200RPMSATA2.52ndSEDw/caH</td>
     <td>B6P51AV-500GB7200RPMSATA2.52ndSEDw/caH</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>SCREEN</td>
     <td>D8T46AV-LCD 14 LED HD+ SVA AG flat</td>
     <td>D9R81AV-LCD 14 LED HD+ SVA AG f/WWAN f</td>
     <td>E2P39AV-LCD 14 LED FHD UWVA AG</td>
     <td>D9R81AV-LCD 14 LED HD+ SVA AG f/WWAN f</td>
     <td>D8T46AV-LCD 14 LED HD+ SVA AG flat</td>
     <td>D9R81AV-LCD 14 LED HD+ SVA AG f/WWAN f</td>
     <td>D8T46AV-LCD 14 LED HD+ SVA AG flat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>OS</td>
     <td>B0U22AV#AC4-Windows 7 Professional 64bit O</td>
     <td>B0U22AV#AC4-Windows 7 Professional 64bit O</td>
     <td>B0U22AV#AC4-Windows 7 Professional 64bit O</td>
     <td>B0U22AV#AC4-Windows 7 Professional 64bit O</td>
     <td>B0U22AV#AC4-Windows 7 Professional 64bit O</td>
     <td>B0U22AV#AC4-Windows 7 Professional 64bit O</td>
     <td>B0U22AV#AC4-Windows 7 Professional 64bit O</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>BATTERY</td>
     <td>D8T39AV-BATT 3C 50 WHr Long Life</td>
     <td>E2P23AV-BATT 3C 24 WHr Long Life</td>
     <td>E2P23AV-BATT 3C 24 WHr Long Life</td>
     <td>E2P23AV-BATT 3C 24 WHr Long Life</td>
     <td>D8T39AV-BATT 3C 50 WHr Long Life</td>
     <td>E2P23AV-BATT 3C 24 WHr Long Life</td>
     <td>D8T39AV-BATT 3C 50 WHr Long Life</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>POWER SUPPLY</td>
     <td>E5K50AV-ACADPT 65 Watt Smart nPFC</td>
     <td>E8G24AV-65W 19.5V/3.3A 2 Pin Reg R-Ang</td>
     <td>E5K50AV-ACADPT 65 Watt Smart nPFC</td>
     <td>E5K50AV-ACADPT 65 Watt Smart nPFC</td>
     <td>E5K50AV-ACADPT 65 Watt Smart nPFC</td>
     <td>E8G24AV-65W 19.5V/3.3A 2 Pin Reg R-Ang</td>
     <td>E5K50AV-ACADPT 65 Watt Smart nPFC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>OTHERS</td>
     <td>
      L6V98AV: WLAN I 3160 ac 1x1 +BT 4.0 LE
      <br>L4Z21AV: WEBCAM Integrated 720p HD<br>L8W85AV#AC4: PWRCORD C5 1.8m BRZL<br>L6E48AV#AC4: KBD TP BRZL
     </td>
     <td>
      L6V98AV: WLAN I 3160 ac 1x1 +BT 4.0 LE
      <br>L4Z21AV: WEBCAM Integrated 720p HD<br>L8W85AV#AC4: PWRCORD C5 1.8m BRZL<br>L6E48AV#AC4: KBD TP BRZL
     </td>
     <td>
      L6V98AV: WLAN I 3160 ac 1x1 +BT 4.0 LE
      <br>L4Z21AV: WEBCAM Integrated 720p HD<br>L8W85AV#AC4: PWRCORD C5 1.8m BRZL<br>L6E48AV#AC4: KBD TP BRZL
     </td>
     <td>
      L6V98AV: WLAN I 3160 ac 1x1 +BT 4.0 LE
      <br>L4Z21AV: WEBCAM Integrated 720p HD<br>L8W85AV#AC4: PWRCORD C5 1.8m BRZL<br>L6E48AV#AC4: KBD TP BRZL
     </td>
     <td>
      L6V98AV: WLAN I 3160 ac 1x1 +BT 4.0 LE
      <br>L4Z21AV: WEBCAM Integrated 720p HD<br>L8W85AV#AC4: PWRCORD C5 1.8m BRZL<br>L6E48AV#AC4: KBD TP BRZL
     </td>
     <td>
      L6V98AV: WLAN I 3160 ac 1x1 +BT 4.0 LE
      <br>L4Z21AV: WEBCAM Integrated 720p HD<br>L8W85AV#AC4: PWRCORD C5 1.8m BRZL<br>L6E48AV#AC4: KBD TP BRZL
     </td>
     <td>
      L6V98AV: WLAN I 3160 ac 1x1 +BT 4.0 LE
      <br>L4Z21AV: WEBCAM Integrated 720p HD<br>L8W85AV#AC4: PWRCORD C5 1.8m BRZL<br>L6E48AV#AC4: KBD TP BRZL
     </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
<div class="arrow_postions">
 <a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
 <br>
 <a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
 </div>
```

[image: please find attached image]

Comment: What do you mean by slider? You want to slide horizontally table rows?

Comment: yes i want to slide horizontally when i click arrows @RuslanNigmatulin

Answer (score 0):

this is just to get you started, you will need to make it work for your exact needs but - add this to you `$(document).ready()` scope

```
$('.arrow_postions a i').click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('fa-arrow-left')){
         $("#fixTable").animate({'margin-left':'-=200'},300)
     }else{
         $("#fixTable").animate({'margin-left':'+=200'},300)
    }
})
```

Comment: It's moving total table, first left 2 columns are fixed remaining part should be slide

Comment: oh, that's totally different - you will have to built two different tables, and place them side by side. `<table>` does not support column freeze or column handeling

Comment: if i take two tables if content extended both table will not be same row

Comment: I made an ugly hack that hides the columns by clicks, it's far from perfect but maybe it could work for your needs: https://jsfiddle.net/g39pd9xz/ if you do want to do it with two tables - have a look at css `table-layout: fixed;`

Comment: only two tables then. it's a pain in the a$$ i know, but it is what it is